# Sending mail via http protocol using spring

Tags: spring, http

In my application, need to send the mail using spring via http protocol.

When i  send the email via http protocol, getting the following error.

```
  Exception in thread "main"  org.springframework.mail.MailSendException:   Mail server connection failed;  nested exception is javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for http. Failed messages: javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for http; message exception details (1) are:
  Failed message 1:
  javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for http


<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
        <property name="port" value="443" />
        <property name="username" value="testuser@gmail.com"/>
        <property name="password" value=<password>/>

          <!-- The name of the property, following JavaBean naming  conventions -->
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">http</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">false</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Gmail (`smtp.gmail.com`) does not support `HTTP` for sending emails; only `SMTP` or `SMTPS`.

Comment: I have used client's host name. it supports http.     // Get system properties
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();

      // Setup mail server
      properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
      properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "http");
      properties.put("mail.transport.port", "443");
      properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
      properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

Comment: You are confusing the Gmail web interface with its SMTP servers. When you send email via Java API, you connect to an SMTP server. In the case of Gmail, the Gmail SMTP servers accept `smtp` or `smtps` as transport protocols (the later preferable). Providing a host name in the connection settings does not make your Java client equivalent to the web browser interface and thereby make `http` a valid SMTP transport protocol.